# Article & Aside bleeding past wrapper and footer

Tags: html, css

Working on code for a school project. I have an div wrapper, article, and aside. The content on my page is mostly in them article/aside, and as a result they extend well past the wrapper and footer. I was suggested a couple of ways to fix this (clearfix::after, .group) but I can't seem to get it. Any way to fix this so the wrapper extends to fit the aside and article?

```css
*{
    margin, padding: 0;
}
@font-face{
    /*font-family:RobotoBlack;
        src: url(fonts/RobotoBlack.ttf)*/
}
@font-face{
    /*font-family:Roboto;
        src: url(fonts/RobotoReg.ttf)*/
}
@font-face{
    font-family:RubikBold;
        src: url(fonts/RubikBold.ttf)
}
@font-face{
    font-family:Rubik;
        src: url(fonts/RubikReg.ttf)
}
@font-face{
    font-family:League;
        src: url(fonts/League.otf)
}
header{
    background-image:url(images/header2.jpg);
    width: 1200px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-radius: 50px 50px 0 0;
}
body{
    background-color: #EAFAF1;
}
div#wrapper{
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #BDFEC2;
    border-radius: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
}
nav{
    margin: 0;
    padding 0;

}
nav ul{
    list-style: none;
    
}
nav li{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #AED6F1;
}
nav a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Roboto Black, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: black;
    font-size: 1em;   
}
nav a:hover{
    color: #F4D03F;
}
nav a:active{
    color: #3498DB;
}
h1{
    padding-left: 50px;
    font-family: League, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
h1::first-letter {
  font-size: 110%;
  color: #145A32;
}
h2{
    padding-left: 50px;
    font-family: RubikBold, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
p, h3{
    padding-left: 30px;
    font-family: Roboto, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
h4{
    padding-left: 20px;
    font-family: Roboto, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #154360;
    font-size: 110%;
}
h5{
    padding-left: 20px;
    font-family: Roboto, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 130%;
}
img{
    margin: 30px;
    border: 3px solid #A569BD;
    max-width: 25%;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 10%;
}
article{
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
    background-color: #82E0AA;
    margin: 1%;
    padding: 1%;
}
article li{
    font-family: Roboto, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
aside{
    float:right;
    width: 30%;
    background-color: #D7BDE2;
    margin:.7%;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #145A32;
}
aside ul {
    font-family: RobotoBlack, Helvetica, sans-serif;
     content: "\266C";
}
blockquote{
    float:right;
    width: 22%;
    background-color: #F1C40F;
    margin:.7%;
    padding: 1%;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: League, Arial sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-image:url(images/bby.jpg);
}
figcaption{
    font-family: League, Arial sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
}

footer{
    background-image:url(images/footer2.jpg);
    width: 1200px;
    height: 100px;
        border-radius: 0 0 50px 50px;
    
}
main, aside{
    padding: 20px;
}
main{
    background-color: #87FE91;
}
.firstletter{
    float: left;
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 1;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.forAttention{
     font-family: RobotoBlack, Helvetica, sans-serif;   
}
.container {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
/*   overflow: hidden; */
/*   display: flow-root; */
}
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Quarantine: Music</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mainstyle.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="group">
        <header></header>
        <h1>Quarantine Site</h1>
        <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="page01.html">Introduction</a></li>
            <li><a href="page02.html">Quarantine: Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="page03.html">Quarantine: Work</a></li>
            <li><a href="page04.html">Quarantine: Music</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <main>
        <h2>Quarantine: Music &#9835;</h2>
        <article>
            <p><span class="forattention">While in quarantine, I ended up finding a large amount of new music to keep me going through out it.</span> I wanted to share what I ended up finding. I've included a link to my favorite song from each album.
            
            Almost none of what I listed is particularly new for most people, but its new for me. I wanted to go into depth of some of the albums in my list.</p>
            
                        <h5>DJ Shadow - Endtroducing...</h5>
            <p>Probably my favorite album I discovered, and easily one of my favorite albums in my entire library. This was an album made <i>entirely</i> of samples. My favorite track is Midnight in a Perfect World. Easily one of my favorite tracks. I bought this album as a physical CD almost instantly.</p>
            <h5>TOBACCO - Ultima II Massage</h5>
            <p>Tobacco is an artist I have heard about for a long time, but never took the time to properly listen to an album by him (at list solo) until now. I had heard a project by him and a rapper that was called <i>Malibu Ken,</i> which I went into detail about two semesters ago, but not one of his solo works. I also knew of him because his music is used often for bumps on Adult Swim. After listening to this album, I was impressed. His sounds are of the rarer variety due to the fact he uses a lot of Analog equipment for his music. He is definetly of the aggresive side of music, and it's deeply enjoyable.</p>
            <h5>Freddie Gibbs & The Alchemist - Alfredo</h5>
            <p>Freddie Gibbs is a rapper that I deeply respect. His pen game and flow is one of the best in the game, and many of his recent projects have been hit after hit. He frequently collaborates with respected producers, Madlib being one of them, and Alchemist is no stranger. Alchemist is one of the most well known and respect producers, being in the game since the 90s. He has done projects for tons of rappers, and his production is great. He tastefully adds to samples he finds to make very smooth tracks that slap hard.</p>
        </article>
        <aside>
            <h4>Links</h4>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vh_DemrVmN8">
                    DJ Shadow - Endtroducing...</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z_bsxqNNWS4">
                    LFO - Sheath</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fXaspWYycXQ">
                    Baauer - Planet's Mad</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iSr8oA3l7pw">
                    TOBACCO - Ultima II Massage</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i8ZLstq919k">
                    Freddie Gibbs & The Alchemist - Alfredo</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q29iibXXiOs">
                    Radiohead - Kid A</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aLykjN0YG-k">
                    deadmau5 - 4x4=12</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hlzb13elEno">
                    Against All Logic - 2012-2017</a></li>
            </ul>
        </aside>

            
            
        </main>
        <footer></footer>
        </div></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add clearfix div and class

```css
*{
    margin, padding: 0;
}
@font-face{
    /*font-family:RobotoBlack;
        src: url(fonts/RobotoBlack.ttf)*/
}
@font-face{
    /*font-family:Roboto;
        src: url(fonts/RobotoReg.ttf)*/
}
@font-face{
    font-family:RubikBold;
        src: url(fonts/RubikBold.ttf)
}
@font-face{
    font-family:Rubik;
        src: url(fonts/RubikReg.ttf)
}
@font-face{
    font-family:League;
        src: url(fonts/League.otf)
}
header{
    background-image:url(images/header2.jpg);
    width: 1200px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-radius: 50px 50px 0 0;
}
body{
    background-color: #EAFAF1;
}
div#wrapper{
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #BDFEC2;
    border-radius: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
}
nav{
    margin: 0;
    padding 0;

}
nav ul{
    list-style: none;
    
}
nav li{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #AED6F1;
}
nav a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Roboto Black, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: black;
    font-size: 1em;   
}
nav a:hover{
    color: #F4D03F;
}
nav a:active{
    color: #3498DB;
}
h1{
    padding-left: 50px;
    font-family: League, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
h1::first-letter {
  font-size: 110%;
  color: #145A32;
}
h2{
    padding-left: 50px;
    font-family: RubikBold, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
p, h3{
    padding-left: 30px;
    font-family: Roboto, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
h4{
    padding-left: 20px;
    font-family: Roboto, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #154360;
    font-size: 110%;
}
h5{
    padding-left: 20px;
    font-family: Roboto, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 130%;
}
img{
    margin: 30px;
    border: 3px solid #A569BD;
    max-width: 25%;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 10%;
}
article{
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
    background-color: #82E0AA;
    margin: 1%;
    padding: 1%;
}
article li{
    font-family: Roboto, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
aside{
    float:right;
    width: 30%;
    background-color: #D7BDE2;
    margin:.7%;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #145A32;
}
aside ul {
    font-family: RobotoBlack, Helvetica, sans-serif;
     content: "\266C";
}
blockquote{
    float:right;
    width: 22%;
    background-color: #F1C40F;
    margin:.7%;
    padding: 1%;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: League, Arial sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-image:url(images/bby.jpg);
}
figcaption{
    font-family: League, Arial sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
}

footer{
    background-image:url(images/footer2.jpg);
    width: 1200px;
    height: 100px;
        border-radius: 0 0 50px 50px;
    
}
main, aside{
    padding: 20px;
}
main{
    background-color: #87FE91;
}
.firstletter{
    float: left;
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 1;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.forAttention{
     font-family: RobotoBlack, Helvetica, sans-serif;   
}
.container {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
/*   overflow: hidden; */
/*   display: flow-root; */
}
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<html>
   <head>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Quarantine: Music</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mainstyle.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="group">
        <header></header>
        <h1>Quarantine Site</h1>
        <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="page01.html">Introduction</a></li>
            <li><a href="page02.html">Quarantine: Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="page03.html">Quarantine: Work</a></li>
            <li><a href="page04.html">Quarantine: Music</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <main>
        <h2>Quarantine: Music &#9835;</h2>
        <article>
            <p><span class="forattention">While in quarantine, I ended up finding a large amount of new music to keep me going through out it.</span> I wanted to share what I ended up finding. I've included a link to my favorite song from each album.
            
            Almost none of what I listed is particularly new for most people, but its new for me. I wanted to go into depth of some of the albums in my list.</p>
            
                        <h5>DJ Shadow - Endtroducing...</h5>
            <p>Probably my favorite album I discovered, and easily one of my favorite albums in my entire library. This was an album made <i>entirely</i> of samples. My favorite track is Midnight in a Perfect World. Easily one of my favorite tracks. I bought this album as a physical CD almost instantly.</p>
            <h5>TOBACCO - Ultima II Massage</h5>
            <p>Tobacco is an artist I have heard about for a long time, but never took the time to properly listen to an album by him (at list solo) until now. I had heard a project by him and a rapper that was called <i>Malibu Ken,</i> which I went into detail about two semesters ago, but not one of his solo works. I also knew of him because his music is used often for bumps on Adult Swim. After listening to this album, I was impressed. His sounds are of the rarer variety due to the fact he uses a lot of Analog equipment for his music. He is definetly of the aggresive side of music, and it's deeply enjoyable.</p>
            <h5>Freddie Gibbs & The Alchemist - Alfredo</h5>
            <p>Freddie Gibbs is a rapper that I deeply respect. His pen game and flow is one of the best in the game, and many of his recent projects have been hit after hit. He frequently collaborates with respected producers, Madlib being one of them, and Alchemist is no stranger. Alchemist is one of the most well known and respect producers, being in the game since the 90s. He has done projects for tons of rappers, and his production is great. He tastefully adds to samples he finds to make very smooth tracks that slap hard.</p>
        </article>
        <aside>
            <h4>Links</h4>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vh_DemrVmN8">
                    DJ Shadow - Endtroducing...</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z_bsxqNNWS4">
                    LFO - Sheath</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fXaspWYycXQ">
                    Baauer - Planet's Mad</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iSr8oA3l7pw">
                    TOBACCO - Ultima II Massage</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i8ZLstq919k">
                    Freddie Gibbs & The Alchemist - Alfredo</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q29iibXXiOs">
                    Radiohead - Kid A</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aLykjN0YG-k">
                    deadmau5 - 4x4=12</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hlzb13elEno">
                    Against All Logic - 2012-2017</a></li>
            </ul>
        </aside>

            
            
        </main>
        <footer></footer>
        </div>
          
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I show your code and see design. I found floating issue in structure, so please review below code to resolved floating issue .

```
main:before, main:after {
    display: table;
    content: "";
    clear: both;
}
```